# How to add image into UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I want to add image at the top left corner of the UIAlertView.

```
UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40)];

NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cloud.png"]];
UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[imageView setImage:bkgImg];


[successAlert addSubview:imageView];

[successAlert show];
```

I am using this code but image does not come up with UIAlertView. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"your Title" message:@"Your   Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Your Title" otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 40, 40)];

NSString *loc = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your Image Name"]];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:loc];
[image setImage:img];

 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   [Alert setValue:image forKey:@"accessoryView"];
}else{
   [Alert addSubview:image];
}

[Alert show];
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Now by using this code.Image is come up in the alert view but coming at the bottom and got stretched from left to right.

Comment: change the imageview frame

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 7.0 +

Use:

```
[successAlert setValue:imageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

Answer (score 1):

First add your image to image assets and give name as `imgCloud` Then update your code to :

```
UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *imageViewCloud = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40)];
UIImage *bkgImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgCloud"];
[imageViewCloud setImage:bkgImg];
[successAlert imageViewCloud forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[successAlert show];
```